# code is working for the few testcases but it not workinng for the testcase solve(10.25,17,5)

Tags: python-3.x

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    meal_cost=float(input(""))
    tip_percent=int(input(""))
    tax_percent=int(input(""))
    x=(meal_cost*tip_percent)/100
    y=(meal_cost*tax_percent)/100
    total_cost=meal_cost+x+y
    print(int(total_cost))
solve(12.00,20,8) 
solve(10.25,17,5)
```

the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 18, in <module>
    solve(10.25,17,5)
  File "solution.py", line 10, in solve
    meal_cost=float(input(""))
EOFError
```

Comment: Why are you asking for user input inside the function, replacing the values you're passing in? Your function should operate only on the arguments it is passed, and rely on the caller to get those from a user if necessary.  It should also `return` its result, either instead of or in addition to printing it.

Comment: there are four testcases its working for three of them but not for the last one.   solve(12.00,20,8)   solve(15.50,15,10)   solve(20.75,10,3)   solve(10.25,17,5)

Comment: How are you inputting the data that those `input` calls are asking for?